# PyCharm: Can't find spark-submit, OS: MAC

Tags: python, pycharm, spark-submit

I am trying to run a test file in PyCharm with unittest.

It errors with this message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'myfolder/opt/spark/./bin/spark-submit':
>   'myfolder/opt/spark/./bin/spark-submit'

Important to note, the path `myfolder/opt/spark/./bin/spark-submit` does not exist, but `myfolder/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit` does. I have no idea why the extra `./` is being added to the path.

The code to the path:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="CSV2Parquet") 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) 
schema = StructType([ StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True)]) 
rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/ash/PycharmProjects/practise/test/departments.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(",")) 
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema) df.write.parquet('/Users/ash/PycharmProjects/practise
```

Comment: do you have a snippet of your code to locate the file?

Comment: sc = SparkContext(appName="CSV2Parquet")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True)])

rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/ash/PycharmProjects/practise/test/departments.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.write.parquet('/Users/ash/PycharmProjects/practise/test/output')

Comment: drag and drop the file directly into the directory folder in PyCharm and see if it runs. `./` is used in a Linux CLI which initiates a program. I am not up on SQL databases but I suspect the code to locating the file automatically tries to initiate the `bin` path